# How to diagnose Maven errors after upgrading to Java 11

Tags: java, maven, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java-11, linkageerror

TLDR: I updated to Java 11 and latest Maven, but Maven is having issues. At first, it does not have enough memory to start the JVM. When the memory is increased >1.5 G, it says it can't allocate the metaspace. Decreasing the memory to 1.2 G or so, it gives a linkage error. What is doing on here?

Details:  Sometimes it complains about illegal reflection by some Google library instead of the link error, although the error messages seem to depend on the order I try things and are hard to reproduce exactly.

Here is the exact output in one case:

```
>export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1600m"
>mvn -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not allocate metaspace: 1073741824 bytes
>export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1000m"
>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T14:33:14-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4
Java version: 11, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-38-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
>mvn install
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 48192 bytes for Chunk::new
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/zach/sync_docs/fs/runner/hs_err_pid5590.log
[thread 5617 also had an error]
#
# Can't open file to dump replay data. Error: Not enough space
>export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1200m"
>mvn install
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libnio.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libnio.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

Further output:

```
>echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1
It won't even work if I ask it to compile a Java 8 JAR, although sometimes it will start trying and fail quickly.
javac successfully compiles a hello world program, and java successfully runs it.
Switching back to Java 8 (either java-8-openjdk or java-8-oracle in case those are different) using update-alternatives fixes the issue (but without Java 11 features).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.boydwebb</groupId>
    <artifactId>familysearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.compiler.version>1.8</java.compiler.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.compiler.version}</target>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>graph-runner</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>org.boydwebb.familysearch.runner.Runner</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
      <!-- unimi dependencies
     the unimi project versions MUST be as shown here -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
        <artifactId>webgraph</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
        <artifactId>sux4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsiutils</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- required for runner utilities -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- command line option parsing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
        <version>6.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hdf5 -->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hdfgroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>hdf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>HDF_Group</groupId>
        <artifactId>HDFJava</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Mind showing your `pom`?

Comment: Added it to the question. I would like to change the compiler version to 1.11 eventually of course. I tried that too but with no different results as far as I could tell.

Comment: I _think_ your maven compiler plugin is out of date, and I would double check that the maven assembly plugin for the latest version as well. I believe `3.8.0` (compiler plugin) works for Java 11. Simply update those versions in the pom file and rebuild

Comment: I updated those numbers and am getting the same errors. And now switching to the Java 8 through update-alternatives doesn't work anymore, which is strange to me.

Comment: If you upgraded to Java 11, it might be a good idea to check what version of Maven you are using with it.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Maven (3.5.4).

Comment: If you are using JDK 9...JDK11 you should use the most recent version of maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0 and change to `<release>..</release>` instead of source/target..furthermore you should use most recent version of JDK 11 (11.0.1) ..Have you had installed an earlier version of Maven on the same system? Please check if there is an M2_HOME env variable existing...

Comment: I eventually nuked all the Java-related things on my system and reinstalled. It still didn't fix the error, but I was eventually able to move from Java 8 to 9, and that is enough for me at this point. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add below to tackle illegal reflection access to surefire and failsafe plugins : `<configuration>
        <argLine>
            --illegal-access=permit
        </argLine>
    </configuration>`